# Can't copy and paste between Linux host and vSphere Windows guest

Tags: linux, vmware, copy-paste, vsphere

Linux host: Archlinux

Windows guest: Win10 with vmware-tools, copy & paste option of Windows guest are enabled

I've tried VMRC and Workstation Pro, copy and paste only work in Gnome(X11), both directions are OK, but other window managers don't

WM that I've tried: Plasma, Qtile, Bspwm.When using X11, only Linux host to Windows guest is OK.

I prefer tilling window manager, what should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is this doesn't work with Wayland.

Gnome(X11) works because X11

Plasma(X11) should also work (I'm on Arch w/ KDE and mine works)

Wayland treats the clipboard a bit different and when your running applications in XWayland (which is where VMRC and Workstation Pro have to run) they can't access the clipboard the same way

Hope that helps

Comment: Plasma(X11) only works with host to guest.

Comment: That's odd. It works fine for me.

Comment: I reinstalled my OS and it works, thanks!